# How to implement fast updating table in windows forms?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, datagridview

I'm currently using `DataGridView` to show my data in tabular format. It has 5 columns.

`Problem:` The data i'm receiving is at a very fast speed, say 5 msec. I'm using `BlockingCollection` to store the data in it from one thread and update the table by fetching data from it from a different thread. What happens is that size of queue keeps on increasing because of speed at which data comes in is very fast.

When i stop sending the data, the `DataGridView` keeps on adding rows which ideally should stop at soon as i stop sending data.

I tried to implement a thread safe circular queue but that didn't work, i miss many messages from it.

Is there any other control that i can use instead of `DataGridView` which is very fast?

Or if someone can tell me how to implement it better?

Comment: are you appending rows or clearing the whole grid before adding next block?

Comment: Are you adding new items to datagridview one-by-one? It is better to make some cashing, and add data to grid by packs (e.g. 100 rows)...

Comment: you mention that you "update the table by *fetching* data", so if "speed at which data comes in is very fast", slow down the cadence in which you fetch the data.

Comment: Also use DoubleBuffering for DataGridView

Comment: Thanks. And is there any in-built thread-safe circular queue in c# like there is BlockingCollection for linear thread-safe data structure?

Comment: @VictorMukherjee - i'm appending rows one after another, not clearing the previous ones. Its like showing a log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that your limiting factor is updating the `DataGridView`, and making a faster queue won't help you. For example, your description indicates that your update loop looks something like this:

```
while (queue not empty)
{
    get queue item
    update data grid
}
```

Every time you update the data grid, there is some layout logic that runs and very possibly tries to update the screen. That is a very expensive operation. It's almost certain that `DataGridView` can't keep up with an insertion rate of 200 records per second if it has to update the screen after every insertion.

The first thing I would suggest is updating the `DataGridView` in batches, calling [SuspendLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout.aspx) before you start a batch, and [ResumeLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resumelayout(v=vs.110).aspx) at the end of the batch. So your loop becomes something like this:

```
int MaxItemsPerBatch = 10;

while (queue not empty)
{
    grid.SuspendLayout();
    int numItems = MaxItemsPerBatch;
    while (numItems > 0 && queue not empty)
    {
        get item from queue
        update data grid
        numItems = numItems - 1
    }
    grid.ResumeLayout();
}
```

Here, the layout logic only runs once per batch, so you should be 10 times as fast. That still gives you a screen update rate of 20 updates per second, which is going to be faster than your user can see. You could probably increase your batch size to 100 without any pushback from users.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It improved the table updation speed. Still i'm missing many messages, i guess that would be because of my circular queue implementation that i'm using. Can you please share most optimal code for thread safe circular queue with me?

Comment: @ankur: My recommendation would be to use the `BlockingCollection`. I know for certain that `BlockingCollection` can easily handle enqueuing and dequeuing more than 200 records per second. It's not the "most optimal," but it's quite fast and works very well. I suspect that your limiting factor is still the `DataGridView` UI update. Did you try increasing the batch size?

Comment: yes you got it right sir, i'm having trouble with `DataGridView`. As of now, i'm using normal `Queue` and suspending layout till scroll event occurs in table. It has improved the UI a little bit, but i need to do better than that.